# Powershell - Item Level Permission by Content Type

Tags: permissions, powershell

Here is the scenario. I only need to run this once as business team just decided their contents are confidential. User Group is "Marketing", will use OOTB "Contribute" and all of marketing items are using "2011 Marketing" content type. The library name is "2011Sales". I need to take out current permissions (also remove inheritance) and only add "Marketing" group with "Contribute" right.

Updated Working Code:

```
$webUrl = "http://inside.national.com/Sales"
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
$list = $web.Lists["2011Sales"]
$ct = "2011 Marketing"
$spgroup = "Custom SP Group"
$rd="Contribute"

foreach ($item in $list.items) {
    If ($item.ContentType.Name -eq $ct)
     {  
        $item.ResetRoleInheritance() # Not sure if this line is needed
        $item.BreakRoleInheritance($false) # I tried $true but did not work, so leave it at $false
        $item.SystemUpdate() # update without changing the modification date

        $group = $web.AllUsers[$spgroup]
        $roledef = $web.RoleDefinitions[$rd]
        $roleass = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($web.SiteGroups[$spgroup])
        $roleass.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roledef)
        $item.RoleAssignments.Add($roleass)
        $item.SystemUpdate() # update without changing the modified date
        Write-Host $item.Name " permission applied"
     }
}
$web.dispose()
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Will the code above implement "Recursive" or "RecursiveAll"?

Comment: The above code is finally working. However, it doesn't apply permissions for items that are in Document Sets and Folders. But I did a Write-Host $item.Name after the last line $item.Update() and i can see the items that are in folders and doc sets.

Comment: OMG, so could you finally decide what the question is?! I've already seen three variants.

Comment: That's because no one is helping me and I would like provide better code for the new reader who is willing to help me.

Comment: This is not working.  if($item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
  {
   $item.BreakRoleInheritance($true)
  }

Comment: Call `update()` after breaking the inheritance, otherwise the new RoleAssingnment won't be applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After breaking the inheritance of an item (item,list,web) you have to call `update()` on that object to make sure the settings are saved to the database. Once these are saved you can start adding/changing the permissions for that item.

BreakRoleInheritance(false) will not copy the permissions of the parent to the new permissionset, supplying true will copy the permissions.

**Updates** (see also Vedran Rasols [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19771/powershell-item-level-permission-by-content-type/19792#19792))

- Using `foreach(item in list.items)` is not recommended, use an SPQuery to select the items and properties you really want, otherwise you will [fetch all data from the DB](https://web.archive.org/web/20120729085025/http://blog.dynatrace.com:80/2009/01/13/sharepoint-only-request-data-that-you-really-need/). See also this [MSDN Best Practices Article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-services/bb687949%28v=office.12%29#WorkingWithFoldersLists)!
- In theory you shouldn't have to call `update()`, but in some strange way in helped solving this issue.

**bonus:** Note that when breaking inheritance on lists [the AllowUnsafeUpdate property of the parent web reverts to false](https://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/BreakRoleInheritance-and-AllowUnsafeUpdates.aspx), which can be annoying.

Comment: Wrong! You don't need to call Update!

Comment: Strange, it did help +monica. And i've seen it on other locations. But would be the cause of the problems? I don't see any difference in the code (apart of the SPQuery class)

Comment: On other hand calling `Update()` cannot hurt (maybe if you have some event handlers in back). If `Update()` was really needed then it would be necessary to call it twice (after `ResetRoleInheritance()` and after `BreakRoleInheritance()`). However biggest problem with code provided in question is foreach loop and lack of recursive scope. I have tested my code and it works without any problems (and I have more then few similar code snippets working in production enviroments). Note about AllowUnsafeUpdate is ok but I doesn't applies to PS scripts (as far as I know).

Comment: @VedranRasol: Actually, the foreach loop grabs everything so Recursive/RecursiveAll is included. I had 300+ doc sets and 200+ folders and 1,000+ files in the root of doc lib and foreach took care all of the items.

Comment: Good thing is that you solved your problem. Bad thing is that people are thinking that foreach on SPList.Items is great (and I am not referring on this answer or question). So every time someone uses foreach little red lamp in my head goes on :)

Comment: Since this answer is now the accepted (and top one) I'll add your remarks to the answer (about foreach, and the update-mystery)

Answer (score 3):

You need to take advantage of [SPQuery class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.aspx). Using CAML query is much, much, much more faster then doing foreach.

Here is script you 'really' want:

```
$webUrl = "http://inside.national.com/Sales"
$listName = "2011Sales"
$ctname = "2011Sales"
$groupname = "Custom SP Group"

# Get web and list
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $webUrl
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]

# Build CAML query
$caml="<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType'/><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where>" -f $ctname
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.Query = $caml
# Set scope to Recursive to include all items from folders and Document Sets
$query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'"
# Get our data (only items with proper ct name)
$items = $list.GetItems($query)

# Set Role Assignment
$spGroup = $web.SiteGroups[$groupname]
$spRoleAssignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($spGroup)
$sproledefinition = $web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"]
$sproleassignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($sproledefinition)

foreach ($item in $items) {
    # This is the fastest way of deleting all permissions
    # First you restore inheritance
    # And then you break it
    $item.ResetRoleInheritance()
    $item.BreakRoleInheritance($false)

    # Add new permission
    $item.RoleAssignments.Add($spRoleAssignment)
}
```

This script will update all items of desired Content Type (including items/files in folders and files in Document Sets). However it will not change permissions of parent Folders or Document Sets.

I have tested this on my dev machine. Feel free to ask additional questions.

Comment: $item.RoleAssignments.Add did not work for me, I had to change it to $item.Web.RoleAssignments.Add

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working code in case someone needs it.

```
$webUrl = "http://inside.national.com/Sales"
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
$list = $web.Lists["2011Sales"]
$ct = "2011 Marketing"
$spgroup = "Custom SP Group"
$rd="Contribute"

foreach ($item in $list.items) {
    If ($item.ContentType.Name -eq $ct)
     {  
        $item.ResetRoleInheritance() # Not sure if this line is needed
        $item.BreakRoleInheritance($false) # I tried $true but did not work, so leave it at $false
        $item.SystemUpdate() # Very Important

        $group = $web.AllUsers[$spgroup]
        $roledef = $web.RoleDefinitions[$rd]
        $roleass = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($web.SiteGroups[$spgroup])
        $roleass.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roledef)
        $item.RoleAssignments.Add($roleass)
        $item.SystemUpdate() #Update item without changing the updated date
        Write-Host $item.Name " permission applied"
     }
}
$web.dispose()
```

Comment: $item.RoleAssignments.Add did not work for me, I had to change it to $item.Web.RoleAssignments.Add