# Changing permission level of a document from contribute to read for members

Tags: permissions, powershell

I need a help .... with a powershell script.

I have a document and i need to modify the existing permission level for members from 'contribute' to 'read'. 
Anyone has any idea how to do that?

In powershell i get the proper page, but then when i retrieve that permission 'members' i dont know exactly how to set from contribute to read ...

Anyone has any idea, would be gratefull for help.

Comment: This question shows how to add contribute permissions: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19771/powershell-item-level-permission-by-content-type